What is the incentive of accepting Coretime computation
Coretime allows users to purchase on-demand computational resources. What motivates network nodes (validators) to accept and execute these computations if the amount of Dot is going to be burned after execution?

From my understanding, Validators still functions the same way as the Parachain auction. The improvement of Polkadot with Agile Coretime is just basically migrating the core assignment process Polkadot 1.0 has with Parachain auction. In Polkadot 1.0, validators and nominators receive the reward from successfully produced blocks. Validators are only incentivized with awareness by participating in the Parachain Block Inclusion Pipeline.
The backing group of validators are chosen and assigned to the Execution Core. Then it has the responsibility to run the execution without any other incentives.
NOTES: This is from materials that I read. Maybe there is something updated and I missed that.
